# Analytically Convert a Robin Boundary Condition Problem into Neumann/Dirichlet Problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

Suppose I have the following boundary condition problem:

$$\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}=s(x) \quad \text{for} \quad  0\le x \le L$$
$$f(0)=f_0$$
$$\alpha \frac{d f(L)}{dx} + f(L)=\beta  $$

where $f_0$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $L$ are known real constants and $s(x)$ is a known real function.

Is it possible to describe this problem (which has a Robin boundary condition) using instead two separate new problems with Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions each? And later combine the solution of these two new problems to obtain the solution of the original problem.

The goal is to avoid Robin boundary conditions.

Comment: What I think you expect is solve some finite number of problems with only-Dirichlet, only-Neumann, or one condition of each type, and then solve a linear equation for the coeffficients. For that, consider the Dirichlet problem with $g(0)=f_0,g(L)=\beta$ and the half-Dirichlet problem with $h(0)=f_0,h'(L)=\beta/\alpha$. Say you have solved these.

Comment: A combination $c g(x)+(1-c) h(x)$ will still satisfy the DE and the left BC. That combination will have $\alpha (c g'(L) + (1-c) h'(L)) + (c g(L) + (1-c) h(L))=c \alpha g'(L) + (1-c)\beta+c\beta + (1-c) h(L)=\beta$ so $c=\frac{h(L)}{h(L)-\alpha g'(L)}$ and then the solution is $\frac{h(L)}{h(L)-\alpha g'(L)} g(x) + \frac{-\alpha g'(L)}{h(L)-\alpha g'(L)} h(x)$. Does that manage your problem?

Comment: Brilliant approach. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, @Ian!

Comment: Also, in principle if you have the general solution you don't really need any particular basis, so like here a general solution is $c_1 + c_2x + \int_0^x \int_0^y s(z) dz dy$ and you can work from there to solve whatever problem you want. But this method doesn't generalize very well.

Comment: Yes, @Ian. I'm aware of this solution. My problem was specifically with the Robin boundary condition. But the separation you proposed does the trick. Thank you, once again!